# While clicking on submit button null value should get passed and not a default one

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Need an amendment to the below code, when I tested this code it was working fine but, what happened is that when user clicks on submit button the default value gets propagate say default value was username then when user doesn't entered anything inside text box the default value passed as a "username" only. But what I  want is the value should get is a blank value when user doesn't enter anything (i.e. null value) although text box may show default value (i.e. username). Below is the code for the same:

```
<FORM action="http://localhost:2013" method="post">
<INPUT type="text" size="25" value="Username" onFocus="if(this.value == 'Username') {this.value = '';}" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Username';}" />
<INPUT type=submit value=Submit>
</FORM>
```

So basically I want display name only for "display" purpose when user puts a cursor into text box everything gets wiped out but if he doesn't enter anything null values.

Comment: what code are you talking about?

Comment: This is the code:
<FORM action="http://localhost:2013" method="post">
<INPUT type="text" size="25" value="Username" onFocus="if(this.value == 'Username') {this.value = '';}" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Username';}" />
<INPUT type=submit value=Submit>
</FORM>

Comment: i did but it doesn't get pasted there!!

Comment: @T.J. Crowder i told you no m not ahtml developer i am working as s/w middleware integration so client is receiving a default value it is in retail domain so on of the field is coming here as a blank value and they are unable to predict................so story is big..hope u got it the gist of it.

Comment: A "blank" value and a "null" value are not the same thing. I would interpret "blank" as meaning an empty string, which is definitely not the same as null. The closest you can get to a null value is to not submit the field in question at all. So which do you want, empty string or null?

Comment: T.J. Crowder thanx bro!!

Comment: yup null value @nnnnnn

Answer (score 1):

Edited Code to match what you needed:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>


  <style type='text/css'>
    input { color:#333; }

input:focus { color:#ccc;transition:color .2s linear 0;
              -webkit-transition:color .2s linear 0;
    -moz-transition:color .2s linear 0 }
input.typing { color:#333; }

  </style>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$("#submit").click(function (){
    if($("#text").val()=="username")
    { $("#text").val("");}

 });
$(function(){
    var input = $('input[name="word"]'), defaulttext = input.attr('data-default');

    input.val(input.attr('data-default'));

    input.on('focus', function(){
        if(input.val() != defaulttext)
            input.addClass('typing');
        else
            input.removeClass('typing');

    }).on('keydown', function(){        
        if(defaulttext == input.val()) input.val('');

        input.addClass('typing');
    }).on('blur', function(){
        if(input.val() == '') input.val(defaulttext);

        that.removeClass('typing');
    });


});

});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body >
     <form method="get" action ="">

        <input type="text" id="text" name="word" data-default="username"></font>

      </br>


          <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="submit">


    </form>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean? its jquery.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you'd actually included the `<script>` element for jquery.js. I was trying to point out that the OP didn't mention jQuery or tag the question as such, so you should explain this in more detail...

Comment: its was tagged as javascript so i didnt think this would be a problem, ill still update my answer.

Comment: it is not working like previous one used to work username should instantly get wiped out moment i enter in the text box

Comment: <html>
<body onLoad="setDefaults();">
<FORM action="http://localhost:2013" method="post">
<label for="user">user</label>
<input type="text" name="user" 
onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=''"    
onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue" 
value="username" maxlength="19" />
<INPUT type=submit value=Submit>
</FORM>
</body>
</html>  if you look at if i click submit on it default username gates passed is there anyway with which i can pass null value? any modification need to do to JS?

Comment: just use my code it has everything u needed..copy paste and if it doesnt work for you then tell me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using HTML5

use a placeholder

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Username">
```

If you can't use HTML5 this plugin may work for you

http://onwebdev.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/jquery-emulating-placeholder-attribute.html

Comment: no this is not a requirement here on unix we don't have chrome or firefox and this won't work in IE so suggest with out HTML5 tag i.e. standard js

Comment: I posted this answer for reference to those using html5 as its the best way to do it under those circumstances

Comment: client won't accept it!! It is not hat easy bro. anyways thanks fo the suggestions

Comment: finally this one solved the my doubt.thanx for you suggestions.<script type="text/javascript">
function blank(a) { if(a.value == a.defaultValue) a.value = ""; }
function unblank(a) { if(a.value == "") a.value = a.defaultValue; }
</script> 
name: <input type="text" value="enter name" onfocus="blank(this)" onblur="unblank(this)" />  .....and please upvote my answer

Answer (score 1):

As this is just to increase UX, if your don't care about old browsers and your are just targeting new browsers use this HTML5 trick:

```
<INPUT type="text" size="25" placeholder="Username" />
```

replace above markup with your original `input` tag.

or use this instead of your `form` tag:

```
<FORM action="http://localhost:2013" method="post" onsubmit='if (document.getElementsByName ("username")[0].value == "Username") document.getElementsByName ("username")[0].value = ""'>
```

also add a `name='username'` in your username `input` tag!

Comment: no this is not a requirement here on unix we don't have chrome or firefox and this won't work in IE so suggest with out HTML5 tag i.e. standard js

Comment: I don't see how this is any different to my answer posted 20 minutes earlier

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice that! :)

Comment: finally this one solved the my doubt.thanx for you suggestions.<script type="text/javascript">
function blank(a) { if(a.value == a.defaultValue) a.value = ""; }
function unblank(a) { if(a.value == "") a.value = a.defaultValue; }
</script> 
name: <input type="text" value="enter name" onfocus="blank(this)" onblur="unblank(this)" />  .....and please upvote my answer

Comment: Actually no! you can not pass null value at all! that because the nature of query strings and post bodies (almost the same thing)! You can alternatively disable the input box by replacing `.value=""` with `.disabled="disabled"` in my answer, but in this case you actually do not pass username field at all and it's up to your backend program to interpret that as null value or non-existing parameter. what language do you use in backend?